# Using screen to keep program alive in a shell script

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

Currently, I'm doing this manually to start a process in the remote server and keep it running in the background using screen. Here's what I do:

```
#On local computer:
ssh me@HOST
#On HOST:
screen
#In screen:
runbackgroundcommand # this will keep running in the foreground in screen so I need to C-A C-D to get out of screen
C-A
C-D
#Out of screen, back on HOST:
exit
#Out of HOST, back on local computer
```

Is there any way to combine all these steps into one shell/python/whatever script on my local computer so that I can just one-click and run it? It really doesn't require any on-run input so I guess it should be do-able...

Comment: Did you try searching/reading existing answers? I found 24 Q/As for `ssh screen`. Some of them look very close. If you still can't resolve your problem, update your Q with your best understanding and people will help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some googling and combining answers of [run commands in screen](https://superuser.com/questions/454907/how-to-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach) and [run commands in ssh](https://thornelabs.net/2013/08/21/simple-ways-to-send-multiple-line-commands-over-ssh.html), here seems to be a working solution. Just googling & trying hard, not sure how it works..

```
#On local computer
ssh me@HOST "screen -dm bash -c runbackgroundcommand"
```

Comment: pluse uno for doing more research. I would epect this to work, but don't know exactly what you have in `runbackgroundcommand `. If you get stuck, I would recommend reframing the Q with a simple problem like `sleep 300 &` as the background task AND posting as a new Q. Good luck.